# Every time I enter a word, the amount of letters in the word will print the error message that many times in c

Tags: c

Slightly confused on where to start to fix this. For example, if I run the program and when it asks to enter positive number, I would put "kobe", the error message will show 4 times, "I'm sorry...." so on.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main(int agrc, char * argv[]) {
      int sum = 0, num, c;
      printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
      scanf_s("%d", &num);
      scanf_s("%c", &c);

      do  
      {  
           sum = num;
           if (num <= 0) {
               printf("I'm sorry, you must enter an integer greater than zero: \n");
               scanf_s("%d", &num);
               scanf_s("%c", &c);
          }

    } while (num <= 0);

    printf("The positive integer was: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are `{ }` after `main` ?  Did you see your condition in `while` number greater than `0` will break the loop .

Comment: Try to debug your program and you'll find the error!

Comment: Where is that word stored in your program ?

Comment: sorry forgot to add that

Comment: What *exactly* are you typing in as your input?

Comment: The `"%c"` format is for a `char`, and will read one character each time. Also, putting that into an `int` is not ok.

Comment: @john sorry i phrased it wrong, debug then > when it ask for integer i type kobe and it shows error message 4 times, bo persson yea I figured but don't know what to do, maybe %s?

Comment: Don't you have to specify a buffer size with `%c` in [`scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/w40768et.aspx)?

Comment: You have not checked the return value from `scanf_s`, you should do this before you try checking the value entered. So when you enter "kobe" for an integer, `num` remains uninitialised. You then execute instructions based on the value of `num` which is **Undefined Behaviour**.

Comment: It gives error message 4 times: once for each letter of "kobe", because none of that input is consumed by `%d` and one char is consumed by `%c`.

Comment: Furthermore, after entering `kobe` and then `123` the program gives the wrong answer, since `sum` was not set from `num` after the repeated input.

Answer (score 1):

Check the return value of `scanf_s` to make sure the input operation actually succeeded (that is, that the user entered a decimal integer):

```
num = 0;
while ( num <= 0 )
{
  printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
  if ( scanf_s( "%d", &num ) == 0 )
  {
    /**
     * A return value of 0 means the user typed in something
     * that isn't a decimal integer; clear out the input
     * stream and try again.
     */
    while ( getchar() != '\n' )
      ; // empty loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong in your code, like why the `%c`, and the integer `c` as well? There doesn't seem to be any use or need for them. You get multiple error messages because `scanf` with `%d` by default doesn't "eat" any non-numeric characters.

I would personally write this code something like this...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int *
int_prompt (char *message, int *number)
{
    printf (message);
    scanf ("%d", number);

    while (1) {
        if (getchar () == '\n') {
            break;
        }
    };

    return number;
}

int
main (void)
{
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    int_prompt ("Please enter a positive integer: ", &num);
    sum = num;

    while (sum <= 0) {
        int_prompt ("I'm sorry, you must enter a positive integer: ", &num);
        sum = num;
    }

    printf ("The positive integer was: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

This is assuming you plan to do something with `sum`, otherwise you can do away with it as well.

Replace `scanf` with `scanf_s` if you like.